# Inserting new line character in notepad

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I am trying to add a new line character to a notepad file. I am using \n but it actually inserts the actual string \n.

Basically I am trying to insert it using a visualforce page.

How Do I Do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The question is confusing. What do you mean by 'add a new line character to a *notepad file*?'
How a are you handling a *file* in visualforce?

If you are trying to insert newlines to a field, you could use `<apex:inputTextArea>` and merge it with that field.

Secondly, since you are using visualforce, you could write out some logic in the *controller* to add newlines.
Hope it helps.

*Update:*
Try using [html codes](http://code.cside.com/3rdpage/us/newLine.html) for new line and carriage return, LF - `&#x0A;`, CR - `&#x0D;`, CRLF - `&#x0D;&#x0A;` instead of using `\n` or `<br />`

Comment: There is an option of creating a file using visualforce. Use <apex:page contentType = "text/plain/#mytext.txt">

Comment: In this case you may use HTML newline codes, linefeed (LF) - `&#x0A;`, Carriage Return (CR) - `&#x0D;` or both CRLF - `&#x0D;&#x0A;` as in this [link](http://code.cside.com/3rdpage/us/newLine.html)